# Array not passing between view controllers ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array that I want to pass between viewcontrollers. From ViewControllerA to ViewControllerB but my result comes out nil.I have tried just about everything.

When I log destViewController.textArraysParsed in ViewControllerA I see the correct result.

```
Array (
Blake
)
```

But when I try to NSLog the array in ViewControllerB the array is Null? I tried the viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewWillLoad methods to try NSLog the array but it comes out nil.

How can I use this array that I made up in ViewControllerA so I can access the array in ViewControllerB.

**ViewControllerA Methods**

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BSKeyboardControls.h"
#import "RegistrationBaseViewController.h"

@interface Register1ViewController : RegistrationBaseViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, BSKeyboardControlsDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {

NSMutableArray *textArrays;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *textArrays;

@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
textArrays =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
NSString *arrayString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.firstNameTxtFld.text];
[textArrays addObject: arrayString];
NSLog(@"Array %@", textArrays);

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segRegister2"]) {
    Register2ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.textArraysParsed = textArrays;
    NSLog(@"destViewController Array %@", destViewController.textArraysParsed);
   }
}
```

Comment: `Weak` or `Strong` pointers?

Comment: Can we see `textArraysParsed`'s declaration?

Comment: is it a property? strong reference?

Comment: is `destViewController` nil?

Comment: you might be allocating the array in the synthesized class,this may be one reason.You need to remove it if you are doing.

Comment: What is `textArrays`? It looks like it's probably an instance variable, but it'd be nice to know for sure. I don't think there's anything wrong with the assignment, but I bet that if you logged `textArrays` along with `destViewController.textArraysParsed` you'd find that it, too, is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do is change strong to retain.

Comment: So you weren't sure of the difference between ARC and MRR?  If that's the case then this issue is the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please mark the correct answer to mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 7 - ARC

Here it didn't work with both "strong" nor "retain". (I let it "strong" in this case).

You have to initialise it first. It worked.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[Simulate class]]) {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueName"]) {
            ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

            vc.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            vc.array insertObject:@"Obj" atIndex:0];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the property method:-

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong)NSMutableArray *textArrays;
```

Answer (score -2):

This is how I usually pass arrays between view controllers. I use NSUserDefaults, unless I miss understood your question.

In your ViewController A

```
NSMutableArray *temp2MutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:temp2MutableArray forKey:@"mySampleArray"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In your ViewController B

```
NSArray *tempArray2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mySampleArray"];

NSMutableArray *temp2MutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray2];
```

Comment: Using the defaults system to pass an object from one view controller to another seems a bit complicated when you could as easily assign a value to a property in the target controller.

Comment: I can't agree with this pattern. UserDefaults are for storing permanent information, just because it can be used to pass information  around globally doesn't mean it should.

Comment: Code I posted here is valid. Just because there are a 100 ways to skin a cat doesn't mean this way is any less wrong.

Comment: But I want to implore readers ***not*** to use this answer. I stand by my downvote.